# Azure Media Services & Playback of video via WPF Application

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-media-services

I'm going around in circles so I turn to SO for a final answer.

I want to develop a small proof of concept application whereby I demonstrate interaction with Azure media services. Everything is great apart from video playback via the MediaElement control.

Everything I have done so far is in WPF, however I cannot work out how to successfully playback published media. I've tried a number of presets I believe are supported by the MediaElement control, however non of the play. They do play however in either Chrome or Silverlight player (smooth streaming.. I know this is SL only but just testing streaming does work)

Is there any WPF control and azure preset combination that will allow streaming via WPF application, or must it be done in silverlight only?

Answer (score 1):

Smooth Streaming playback is available for WinRT, Silverlight and Windows Phone -- but not WPF. You can, however, get around it if you [host a Silverlight player within your WPF application](http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com/).

The Media Services preset you want is one of the Smooth Streaming presets (or "Playback via PC or Mac" if you stick with the simpler presets).